# tabcontrol OwnerDrawFixed right to left in c#

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I wanted to add X button for each tab.
The drawMode is OwnerDrawFixed. it works fine if it left to right.
Once I allow RightToLeftLayout = true and RightToLeft = true, it does not look good because that he still adds the string from left to right, while that tab add from right to left.

How do I make it that string will also be right to left?

[image]

[image]

```
private void addCloseButton(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //This code will render a "x" mark at the end of the Tab caption. 
    e.Graphics.DrawString("x", e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Right - 15 , e.Bounds.Top +4 );
    e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left+4, e.Bounds.Top+4);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

}

private void actionClose(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Looping through the controls.
    for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count; i++)
    {
        Rectangle r = tabControl1.GetTabRect(i);
        //Getting the position of the "x" mark.
        Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 15, r.Top + 4, 12, 10);
        if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("?האם אתה רוצה לסגור טאב זה", "אישור", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look to this answer [Close button to TabPage with RightToLeft property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34509304/4340666)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `StringFormat` with `FormatFlags` flag set to `StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft` to the `DrawString()`:

```
StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft);

var bounds = new RectangleF(.. set actual bound rectangle for text... )    

e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, bounds, drawFormat);
```

Comment: I do not know what to put in var bounds = new RectangleF(). 
If I put the point (0,0,845,592) that 845,592 is the size of the tabcontrol, so it first comes out fine and after that it tramples on it.

Comment: try to pass e.Bounds first (bounds of the tab header), then adjust it to avoid text overlap with [X]

Comment: i can't to add after e.Bounds header, i have Top or Right or Left and etc. i have 4 fields that I need to add to new RectangleF(), and I'm get involved. if i put: var bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Right+30); it does not show me the string.

Comment: try RectangleF(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bound.Width, e.Bounds.Height)

Comment: It's not work well. It starts from left to right and any additional tab add from left to right As it was before it.

Comment: Make sure that both RightToLeft and RightToLeftLayout is set to true for tab control. RightToLeftLayout controls tab header order (and affects e.Bounds values)

Comment: Of course, RightToLeft is set to Yes and RightToLeftLayout is set to true.

Answer (score -1):

check here http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/visualstudio2005.aspx you should use textrenderer instead of drawstring