# Close button for TabPages of Right To Left TabControl c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, right-to-left, tabpage

I want to add a close button to `TabPages` of a `TabControl`. I try this code and it works fine with a Left To Right TabControl:

```
private Point _imageLocation = new Point(13, 5);
private Point _imgHitArea = new Point(13, 2);

this.tabControl2.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;

tabControl2.DrawItem += TabControl2_DrawItem;

private void TabControl2_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Image img = new Bitmap(GestionP.Properties.Resources.Close);
        Rectangle r = e.Bounds;
        r = this.tabControl2.GetTabRect(e.Index);
        r.Offset(2, 2);
        Brush TitleBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Font f = this.Font;
        string title = this.tabControl2.TabPages[e.Index].Text;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(title, f, TitleBrush, new PointF(r.X, r.Y));

        if (tabControl2.SelectedIndex >= 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(r.X + (this.tabControl2.GetTabRect(e.Index).Width - _imageLocation.X), _imageLocation.Y));
        }

    }
        catch (Exception) { }
}

    private void tabControl2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tc = (TabControl)sender;
        Point p = e.Location;
        int _tabWidth = 0;
        _tabWidth = this.tabControl2.GetTabRect(tc.SelectedIndex).Width - (_imgHitArea.X);
        Rectangle r = this.tabControl2.GetTabRect(tc.SelectedIndex);
        r.Offset(_tabWidth, _imgHitArea.Y);
        r.Width = 16;
        r.Height = 16;
        if (tabControl2.SelectedIndex >= 1)
        {
            if (r.Contains(p))
            {
                TabPage TabP = (TabPage)tc.TabPages[tc.SelectedIndex];
                tc.TabPages.Remove(TabP);

            }
        }
    }
```

But when I set the property `RightToLeftLayout = true` and `RightToLeft = true`  it doesn't work, `TabPage` titles don't appear and also close button.

So how to fix the code in a way that accepts `RightToLeft` property?

Comment: By drawing on a TabControl, it means you need to process `RightToLeft` property by yourself, try editing your code in `TabControl2_DrawItem`

Comment: Wher to edit? i tried changing r.offset but this work just for the first tabpage

Comment: in the `TabControl2_DrawItem` block, add a `if(RightToLeft)` condition

Comment: But how to set the other code inside the condition, i tried a lot but it doesn't work

Comment: The native TabControl is a horrible bag 'o bugs, GetTabRect() returns the wrong rectangle.  Shifting it to the right is required, this is not exactly straight-forward.

Comment: I set r.offset(1180, 2) and the rectangle is now is the right but this jus for the first tab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a function to translate coordinates of a rectangle to RTL coordinates in a container:

```
public static Rectangle GetRTLCoordinates(Rectangle container, Rectangle drawRectangle)
{
    return new Rectangle(
        container.Width - drawRectangle.Width - drawRectangle.X,
        drawRectangle.Y,
        drawRectangle.Width,
        drawRectangle.Height);
}
```

And when painting in RTL mode, calculate coordinates this way:

```
tabRect = GetRTLCoordinates(this.tabControl2.ClientRectangle, tabRect);
```

Also you should draw your strings using an `StringFormat` and set it to use `StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft` when you are in RTL mode and draw string in the translated rectangle using the string format:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl2.TabPages[e.Index].Text, 
                      this.Font, Brushes.Black, tabRect, sf);
```

You can encapsulate all codes in a `CustomTabControl` inheriting `TabControl`.

**Screenshot**

[image]
[image]

**The whole code could be:**

I suppose you have a close image somewhere like `Properties.Default.Close` and assign it to `this.CloseImage`. Here is the image I used: [image]

I also set the `this.tabControl2.Padding = new Point(10, 3);` to provide additional free space for drawing the image.

Also you can simply add your criteria of not closing first tab.

```
Image CloseImage;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tabControl2.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    tabControl2.DrawItem += TabControl2_DrawItem;
    tabControl2.MouseClick += tabControl2_MouseClick;
    CloseImage = Properties.Resources.Close;
    this.tabControl2.Padding = new Point(10, 3);
}


private void TabControl2_DrawItem(object sender, 
                                  System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var tabRect = this.tabControl2.GetTabRect(e.Index);
        tabRect.Inflate(-2, -2);
        var imageRect = new Rectangle(tabRect.Right - CloseImage.Width,
                                 tabRect.Top + (tabRect.Height - CloseImage.Height) / 2,
                                 CloseImage.Width,
                                 CloseImage.Height);

        var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        if (this.tabControl2.RightToLeft == System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes &&
            this.tabControl2.RightToLeftLayout == true)
        {
            tabRect = GetRTLCoordinates(this.tabControl2.ClientRectangle, tabRect);
            imageRect = GetRTLCoordinates(this.tabControl2.ClientRectangle, imageRect);
            sf.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl2.TabPages[e.Index].Text,
                              this.Font, Brushes.Black, tabRect, sf);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(CloseImage, imageRect.Location);

    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}

private void tabControl2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    for (var i = 0; i < this.tabControl2.TabPages.Count; i++)
    {
        var tabRect = this.tabControl2.GetTabRect(i);
        tabRect.Inflate(-2, -2);
        var imageRect = new Rectangle(tabRect.Right - CloseImage.Width,
                                 tabRect.Top + (tabRect.Height - CloseImage.Height) / 2,
                                 CloseImage.Width,
                                 CloseImage.Height);
        if (imageRect.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            this.tabControl2.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static Rectangle GetRTLCoordinates(Rectangle container, Rectangle drawRectangle)
{
    return new Rectangle(
        container.Width - drawRectangle.Width - drawRectangle.X,
        drawRectangle.Y,
        drawRectangle.Width,
        drawRectangle.Height);
}
```

Comment: @Dotnet Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kuxe.png). You can play with `this.tabControl2.Padding = new Point(10, 3);`.

Comment: I made the `Padding` to **4**, because for some reason the text was lower than the **X**... Thanks for this :)

Comment: Is there a way to add a hover image for the X? e.g. if I hover the mouse over the X button, it will turn into the image I specify? Thanks :)

Comment: @Momoro the logic for paint is in `DrawItem` event handler. The logic for checking the mouse position to see if it's over the close button can be in `MouseMove`. To force the repaint, you need to call `Invalidate` method of the control. Give it a try and ask a linked question if you needed some help. All the community users can help you, however feel free to tag me here in the comments, so I may also share more idea if I have anything in mind 

Comment: But, I am not attempting to re-draw the **entire** control, I just need to re-draw the tabpage. Is this possible? Thanks :D

Comment: @Momoro `Invalidate` has an overload which invalidates a specific rectangle of the control. The basic idea of paint is: do all paintings in paint event, when you need to repaint, for example because of a click, because of a mouse move, etc, call invalidate.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it just makes the X image disappear.. Shouldn't it just change the image, or am I doing something wrong? I can send you my code through another comment if it's needed 

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to override drawing:
1. select tab control.
2. set `RightToLeft` property to `yes` **AND**  `RightToLeftLayout` property to `true`.

now all tab pages are aligned right to left (the trick is that `RightToLeft` and  `RightToLeftLayout` properties must be set to changed, dont know why Microsoft did it that way...)