# C# winforms changing look of owner drawn tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

I've used the answer to this question to develop tabs that have a add tab and remove tab functionality: [Close button for TabPages of Right To Left TabControl c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508176/close-button-for-tabpages-of-right-to-left-tabcontrol-c-sharp/34509304#34509304)

The look here is very different compared to the default tabs look. How do I paint the custom control in the above question to make it look like the default tabs look? Images below to demonstrate what I mean.

This first image here shows the default look without having the tabcontrol being overriden by ownerdrawmode.

[image: This is the default look]

This second image here shows the look from the answer in the link.

[image]

Comment: what about another button outside the Tabcontrol to close the active tab?

Comment: How would that work if I were to dynamically add tabs?

Comment: You can always detect the tabs collection and the active one

Comment: The focus of that answer is on adding close button for right to left tab control. You can use `TabRenderer` to draw tab items with visual styles.

Comment: Using tabrenderer seems to override the close button. I actually need the close button.

Comment: Draw close button after calling `TabRenderer.DrawTabItem`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using custom drawn controls instead of those tab headers (i guess thats how they are called) and loading user control instead of that tab page? it can be easily done: here is "tabs" (user controls) sample https://github.com/WithoutCaps/LimitlessUI/blob/master/LimitlessUI/TabsAdapter_WOC.cs

(there is project demo too )